# This angularJS ng-repeat just won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know what's going on, for some reason AngularJS is acting flakey:

```
    <p ng-repeat="item in supplierTeamObjects">
        <a href="#" ng-click="selectSupplierTeam(item.id)">[[item.name]]</a> 
    </p>    
                    ^--NG-REPEATS PERFECTLY
    <br>

    <div ng-init="materialDataStructure = [{'name':'Thorium','company':'Company Name not here','description':'No description','image':'materials/image_4.jpg','product_id':'1922004'}]">
        <p ng-repeat="item in materialDataStructure">
            <p>[[item.name]]</p> 
        </p>
    </div>      ^--NOT WORKING
```

So my actual app has `materialDataStructure` get returned via AJAX. But After almost an hour of scratching my head, I copied and pasted verbatim the smallest AJAX response and just hard coded it into the `ng-init` to get to the bottom of why this thing isn't looping at all...

The very last div tag will not do the ng-repeat successfully like the first ng-repeat in the p tag. What's happening?? At first I thought my AJAX response wasn't coming back right but even after hard coding it into an ng-repeat, it still doesn't loop but the first ng-repeat works just fine via AJAX...

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do placing `p` inside another `p`?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: please provide plunker or detailed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<p>[[item.name]]</p>` inside the ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the P tag inside P

remove it and it will work fine

```
<div ng-init="materialDataStructure = [{'name':'Thorium','company':'Company Name not here','description':'No description','image':'materials/image_4.jpg','product_id':'1922004'}]">
        <p ng-repeat="item in materialDataStructure">
            [[item.name]] 
        </p>
    </div>
```

I am assuming might have replaced `{{` with `[[` in the app config

Here's the plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sig1bXbwnQ5gPtEwL2u3?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Vamsi V answer is correct, Here is the explanation why p tag did not work

From HTML5 doc http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

*A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.*